# Sprite right align

Tags: html, css

Even though my `#tbr` div **align** is set to **right**, sprites keep aligning to the left. Any ideas why?

Normal text, links and images work fine. (aligned to right, with 20px right margin, like it is supposed to be).

**HTML:**

```
<div id="topbar">
<div id="tbl">abc</div>
<div id="tbc">center</div>
<div id="tbr">
<div id="bar">
<a href="#" id="sound"></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#topbar {

    width:100%;
    height:36px;
    padding-top:12px;
    background-color:#e7e6e6;
    border-top:1px solid #d0cdcd;
    border-bottom:1px solid #d0cdcd;


}

#tbl {float:left; width: 30%; text-align:left; padding-left:20px;}
#tbc {display:inline-block; text-align:center; width: 30%;}
#tbr {float:right; width: 30%; text-align:right; padding-right:20px;}

#bar {margin-top:-5px;}

#bar a {

    height:35px;
    display:block;
    background-image:url(http://goo.gl/yLbQ9);
    float:left;
}

#sound {width:35px; background-position:0 0;}
```

> **JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/B4n9T/**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I am following you here completely, but I think this might be your issue

```
#bar a {
    height:35px;
    display:block;
    background-image:url(http://goo.gl/yLbQ9);
    float:left; //you want this to be right
}
```

Comment: oh of course, what a stupid mistake. And i havent even noticed it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/B4n9T/3/

Here's how it's fixed:

position:relative; on #tbr and to stop it being incorrectly positioned again i've set the width:auto; on it too.

Comment: The problem was just a float:left on #bar a in my code. Thanks for finding a workaround. :)

Comment: ahh yes, totally didn't notice that :)

Answer (score 1):

[See this](http://jsfiddle.net/B4n9T/4/)

Is this What you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

Just give **float:right** to you **#bar a** like this:-

```
#bar a {

    height:35px;
    display:block;
    background-image:url(http://goo.gl/yLbQ9);
    float:right;
}
```

i hope this will help you....
see the demo:- http://jsfiddle.net/B4n9T/5/